# Getting non scrolling height of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the height of the current view port or screen which is currently shown. That means if some of the part of the page is not shown due to overflowing, it should not include that.

All of the following gave me same result, which includes the scrolling/non visible area of the page -

```
$(document).height();
$(windows).height();
document.body.clientHeight;
```

Can someone please let me know how can I know the height of the currently visible area of document in either JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your problem. `$(window).height()` should return the height of the viewport excluding anything which requires you to scroll. If you take a look into the [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/), you'll read:

```
// Returns height of browser viewport
$( window ).height();

// Returns height of HTML document
$( document ).height();
```

An alternative is using `window.innerHeight`. But this returns the same as `$(window).height()` for me.

For getting the height of the screen, you can use `screen.height` ([screen object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp)). This will return the height of the entire screen (including the browsers's top bar and the windows taskbar). `screen.availHeight` in contrast includes only the browser's top bar.

Comment: Yes I've tried both of them already. They are returning values in 3K something. While my screen is hardly 1K. The exact height which I require is 945, but both of them are not returning it.
I want these values so that I can dynamically resize the sections to take up whole screen(or whole viewport). I achieved it by setting the value to 100vh. But that's not how I want it.

Comment: Did you mind giving a DOCTYPE to the HTML document?  Seems like there'a a known problem with incorrect values if it's missing.